# How can I force fetch_feed to return real URL?

Tags: feed

For Some websites `fetch_feed` return feedburner or similar URL. How can I force it to return real URL? Or is there any other way to get the real URL?

Comment: `fetch_feed` doesn't return a URL. You give it a URL and it returns a SimplePie object.

Comment: @JacobPeattie As a URL, I mean URL of SimplePie object

Comment: Objects don't have a URL. Could you update the question to show what you're trying to do with `fetch_feed()` in your code?